# How does nested RxJs retry operators work?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using RxJs 5 lettable operators in Angular 5.
Based on this code sample,  how will the retry work? will the error propagate to the first retry and then if it fails it will propagate to the second?

First observable:

```
first() {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
     observer.error('Something went wrong!')})
  }).pipe(retry(3))
}
```

Second observable subscribe method call:

```
first().pipe(retry(1)).subscribe()
```

Thank you!

Comment: The observer's `error` method does not return an `Observable`, so the call to `pipe` is not valid.

Comment: @cartant Thanks, I just updated my sample code.

Comment: Why not try out what happens?

Comment: @IngoBürk I tried but can't seem to understand what happens, Also what boggles me is which observable will be re-subscribed is it the one that originated the error or the whole entire observables sequence that are piped all together?

Comment: You can slap on `do` side effects at all points that log. That gives a really good picture of what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting stream effectively looks like this:

```
Observable.create(...).pipe(retry(3), retry(1));
```

So the `subscribe` will perform first subscription, then `retry(3)` will perform 3 subscriptions to the source observable and after that will propagate the error to the next `retry(1)`, which in turn will run the preceding sequence `Observable.create(...).pipe(retry(3))` again so if you put `console.log('subscribed')` into producer function you'll have 8 log entries.

You can learn more about the `retry` operator and its variations [here](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/retry).

Comment: Thanks, that explains it well. However, does that also mean that in the retry will resubscribe to the observable that emitted the error or the whole piped sequence? it might not apply to this case since there is only one observable  but what if there are more observables that are piped together would it resubscribe to the one that emitter the error only? or restart the entire observable sequence?

Comment: @Mo'menEl-Zeiny, retry will resubscribe to the stream before retry, so if you have `of().map().filter().retry()`, `retry` will subscribe to the `of().map().filter()`